# Mocking URLSessionDataTask without using init

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to mock my `URLSession` instance and after researching on StackOverflow, I've seen that one approach is to create a mocked URLSessionDataTask and call the completion handler on `resume()`:

```
class URLSessionDataTaskMock: URLSessionDataTask {
    private let closure: () -> Void

    init(closure: @escaping () -> Void) {
        self.closure = closure
    }

    override func resume() {
        closure()
    }

    override func cancel() {
        closure()
    }
}

class URLSessionMock: URLSession {
    typealias CompletionHandler = (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void
    var data: Data?
    var error: Error?
    override func dataTask(
        with _: URLRequest,
        completionHandler: @escaping CompletionHandler
    ) -> URLSessionDataTask {
        let data = self.data
        let error = self.error
        return URLSessionDataTaskMock {
            completionHandler(data, nil, error)
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I'm facing is that `URLSessionDataTask.init` has been deprecated as of iOS 13:

> 'init()' was deprecated in iOS 13.0: Please use -[NSURLSession dataTaskWithRequest:] or other NSURLSession methods to create instances

Is there an updated approach to achieve the same goal?

Comment: Whoever said that was the "most popular" way? Actually the right approach is to subclass URLProtocol. See my https://github.com/mattneub/CheckWeather/blob/master/CheckWeatherTests/JSONTalkerTests.swift

Comment: Your proposed approach is indeed quite clean. I miss one use case, though, and that  is when `Data` is nil. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @gmoraleda. may you please share your solution.

Comment: I'm currently using @matt's proposal